# socket.removeListener not working in socket io client

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to disconnect sockect io connection but after reload the page reconnect on show old Listener also. In short say unable to socket.removeListener. I am using socket io 4.5.1

Comment: We can't actually solve your problem if there is no code. Please add a [mre] so that we can understand the situation and attempt to figure out why it doesn't work. Also, what have you tried? Did you observe anything else while trying to troubleshoot the problem? [Edit] your question and include the details required. Thank you for understanding. See this help center article on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You question is very ambiguous and you definitely should read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking question in here.

I'm only answering this question because i faced a similar problem and i hope to help someone else that end up here.

In the socket-io [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/) it's stated that you can use `socket.off('event', function)` to remove the event a specific listener. So with that you can do it like this:

```
const myFunction = args => {
    console.log(args)
}

//on mount
socket.on('myListener', myFunction)

//onDismount
socket.off('myListener', myFunction)
```

The problem that i faced was that i was providing a arrow function to the event listener like so:

```
socket.on('myListener', (args) => myFunction(args))
```

But this method is **WRONG** because when you are associating the arrow function to the event listener instead of the function **"myFuncion"**, and then when you try to remove the event listener with `socket.off('myListener', myFunction)`, it will not work because the function that is associated with the listener is not **"myFunction"** but the arrow function.

It's not mentioned in the documentation, but you can see witch events listeners are active on the socket object, `socket._callbacks`